# Can squaring a discrete random variable change the probability distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

let $X$ be a discrete random variable that takes a value of $\{-2,2\}$  and the probability distribution of each is $\{0.5,0.5\}$

with this in mind:

$X^2$ only takes value $\{4\}$ with the probability of $\{1\}\cdots(\%)$

in this case $X$ have 2 values which has a probability of not 0 but $X^2$ has only 1 value which the probability is not 0.

is this correct or am I missing something? I am having trouble understanding the $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ part of

$\displaystyle\mathbb{V}[X]\equiv
\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(x-\mathbb{E}[X])^2p(x)=
\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2\cdots(\$)$

to avoid confusion, let $Y=X^2$

by definition $\displaystyle\mathbb{E}[X]\equiv\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}x\cdot p(x)$

with this, if we plug in $Y$ into the formula

it becomes $\displaystyle\mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_{ y\in\mathcal{Y}}y\cdot p(y)$

if we bring back substitute $Y$ back to $X^2$ it should become
$\displaystyle\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{ y\in\mathcal{X^2}}y\cdot p(y)\cdots(@)$

but when I search about it everywhere it seems that everyone is doing this calculation for $X^2$:

$\displaystyle\mathbb{E}[X^2]\equiv\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}x^2\cdot p(x)\cdots(*)$

I am confused because it seems that the process of creating the new distribution for $X^2$ is entirely skipped by most of the explanations I saw. does $(@)$ and$(*)$ produce the same result? $(*)$ is understandable if $X$ is guaranteed to be positive, but for distributions like $(\%)$ it confuses me.

furthermore if I try to compare $(\$)$ left-hand and right-hand side:
$
\displaystyle\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(x-\mathbb{E}[X])^2p(x)=
\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$

$
=\displaystyle\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(x^2-x\cdot\mathbb{E}[X]+(\mathbb{E}[X])^2)p(x)=
\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$

$
=\displaystyle\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(x^2-x\cdot\mathbb{E}[X])p(x)+\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(\mathbb{E}[X])^2p(x)=
\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$

$
=\displaystyle(\mathbb{E}[X])^2+\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(x^2-x\cdot\mathbb{E}[X])p(x)=
\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$

$
=\displaystyle(\mathbb{E}[X])^2+\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(x^2-x\cdot\mathbb{E}[X])p(x)=
\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$

$
=\displaystyle2(\mathbb{E}[X])^2+\sum_{ x\in\mathcal{X}}(x^2-x\cdot\mathbb{E}[X])p(x)=
\mathbb{E}[X^2]$

is this correct? I'm confused.

Comment: Where is the confusion?  In this case, $E[X]=0$ so it is perfectly true that $E[X^2]-E[X]^2=E[X^2]$.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My confusion mostly lies on calculating $E[X^2]$ since most calculations I see straight up uses $(*)$ instead of creating $X^2$ distribution first and then calculating the expected value as shown in $(@)$

Comment: But, as to the computation, there is no significant difference between considering the values $x^2$ might take as $x$ varies or considering the set of values $x^2$, it's just a question of which way is easier.  Typically, one know the probability for each value $x$ so it makes sense to sum over those, but  in this case (for example) it's not really any harder to compute the probabilities of each possible value of $x^2$.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification.